# Terminating com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism due to inactivity

Tags: boot, 16.04

I found the title line in syslog. I believe this is what's causing my boot time to be unusually long. When starting Ubuntu, between me seeing GRUB and me seeing Gnome there is an unusually long hang on a grey screen. The full excerpt from syslog is:

```
Aug 13 19:57:09 mbpc dbus[3104]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Aug 13 19:57:09 mbpc dbus[3104]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism'
Aug 13 19:57:39 mbpc com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[3104]: Running com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism.
Aug 13 19:57:39 mbpc com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[3104]: Terminating it after 30 seconds of inactivity.
Aug 13 19:57:39 mbpc com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[3104]: Terminating com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism due to inactivity.
```

These 30 seconds are probably what I'm feeling as a long hang. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Where did you get this com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism service?

Comment: @AnwarShah I just found these lines in syslog, i don't know what this service is or what it does.

Answer (score 0):

That service came from the package `screen-resolution-extra` whose description says, it is "Extension for the GNOME screen resolution applet". I think, you can safely remove this package without losing much functionality. To remove, use this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove screen-resolution-extra
```

Then reboot and see if the problem fixed.

Comment: Removing that package removed the Nvidia X Server Settings application, which screwed up my resolution, so I have to reinstall it. It did not remove the delay in startup, and looking at the logs, the same error was given this time. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo systemctl disable com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism`? It will disable the service at boot process.